# Unable to fetch my data from JSON file due to fetch api error

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

So I made a table with data coming from a json file. It worked last time I used it and I came back after about a week to this error :

script.js:5 Fetch API cannot load file:///(file location). URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

my script.js:5 is fetch('data.json')

this is how I was getting my json data into my javascript file:

```
fetch('data.json')
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
    generateTable(data);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err);
});
```

It is my understanding I need my json file to come from a url, is there an easy way to do that? Alternatively, is there another way to get my data into my javascript program?

Comment: The file has to be stored somewhere, with somewhere a location, an address that you know, where is actually this file?

Comment: You have to serve your app from a webserver and not open it directly from the filesystem

Comment: Your whole problem is you can't use ajax (fetch()) in `file://` protocol. You need to implement a localhost server and use that to run your app. There are numerous easy ways to get a localhost server running on your machine

Comment: the file is in a location, I just didn't want to put the location in the post. I think I will go with a local server. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for testing purposes you can upload your json file to a server that supports direct links for txt files, [file.io](https://file.io) and [filebin.net](https://filebin.net) may do so but this is not a very good idea.

you can always install apps like Xamp or Mamp which provide you with a local development environment.

if you are just developing a front end project and don't want full featured apps like Xamp then you can use brackets editor that lets you to preview in localhost with http protocol.

of course all the suggestions above were for development stage of your website, in case of a production level website you should upload your files to a server.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will try to use a local host/server